# Dynamic format of words within a gettext translation in python

Tags: python, localization, internationalization, gettext

I have some strings that I need to translate, but I only know some parts of the string while other parts are dynamic and don't need to be translated. Let's say something like this:

```
msgid "We found {something} in the hallway"
msgstr "They lost {something} somewhere"
```

So if that was the PO file and I wanted to translate "We found a ball in the hallway", I'd end up with "They lost a ball somewhere".

This is fine if {something} is actually a variable with a value you .format() in afterwards. But the sentences I need translations of are generated elsewhere and so have no variables that can be formatted in after translation, unless I separate the original sentence to its components.

Any ideas how I solve this?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "generated elsewhere"? To me it looks like your real problem is that you have to find a way to extract these strings first. Without being able to extract them, you cannot creaet a translation file. Solve that problem first or give more details on what you are trying to do. And, please, give a more realistic example. "Translating" an English sentence into a different English sentence is not what gettext is used for. So, what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Use sprintf() with placeholders. [This is for WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers#HTML), but the principles apply to your question. Look at the 2nd example.